# Propel & Symfony2 - NULL in auto increment field

Tags: php, symfony, primary-key, auto-increment, propel

I have a problem with inserting new data into table, with Propel. Let's say the table name is `my_tables` and this is a piece of its Resources\config\schema.xml:

```
<table name="my_tables" phpName="MyTable">
   <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
   ...
```

The code does this:

```
$objMyTable = new MyTable();
$objMyTable->setSomeColumn('SomeValue')
        ->setOtherColumn('OtherValue')
        ->save();
```

I would expect something like this to get generated:

```
INSERT INTO my_tables ('id', 'some_column', 'other_column') VALUES (123, 'SomeValue', 'OtherValue');
```

where the 123 would be generated auto-increment id, but I always get NULL instead of that 123 value, and consequently - an error reported. Apparently the auto-increment is not working for this field. Any ideas where am I wrong?

BTW, the table itself is set up in mysql database so it does have the auto-increment id, but obviously the PHP part generates wrong SQL.

---

As an answer to question in comments - no customizations were done on Base classes generated by propel for this table. I don't have additional entity class for this table, while the example of the Model/map/MyTableTableMap (ignore the TableTable part, it's just an example name) is below:

```
 public function initialize()
    {
        // attributes
        $this->setName('my_tables');
        $this->setPhpName('MyTable');
        $this->setClassname('Bundle\\Model\\MyTable');
        $this->setPackage('src.Bundle.Model');
        $this->setUseIdGenerator(true);
        // columns
        $this->addPrimaryKey('id', 'Id', 'INTEGER', true, null, null);
        $this->addColumn(...);
... // other addColumn() calls

     // validators
    } // initialize()
```

---

**After realizing my mistake in blaming the Propel for this, this question is no longer valid. There was a data issue and a unique-index not being honored that caused it.**

Comment: have you created entity class for this? can you show it?

Comment: I have no idea if this will work. but just a trial, can you make such a small change from type="integer" to type="INTEGER" in 
<column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>

Comment: I'm sorry guys, it was my fault and not related to primary key. There was some index on that table (with confusing name) which was really failing. I wasn't aware that that index is existing and due to it's name didn't really figure out what was it all about.

Comment: One more thing - the SQL I expected to see formed for MySQL was also wrong. Proper value *would* be: INSERT INTO my_tables ('id', 'some_column', 'other_column') VALUES (NULL, 'SomeValue', 'OtherValue'); with NULL in it, as it would be MySQL's job to insert the actual value, and not the Propel's.